# How to pass configurations from hive script to UDF

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, apache-pig

In pig, you can pass a configuration from your pig script to pig UDF via `UDFContext`. For example,

```
// in pig script
SET my.conf dummy-conf

// in UDF java code
Configuration conf = UDFContext.getUDFContext().getJobConf();
String myConf = conf.get("my.conf");
```

So, is there a similar way to pass configuration from a hive script to a hive UDF? For example, if I have `set MY_CONF='foobar'` in a hive script, how can I retrieve that in a java UDF, which needs to consume the value of `MY_CONF`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of extending `UDF` class, you can try subclassing `GenericUDF`. This class has the following method you can override:

```
/**
 * Additionally setup GenericUDF with MapredContext before initializing.
 * This is only called in runtime of MapRedTask.
 *
 * @param context context
 */
public void configure(MapredContext context) {
}
```

`MapredContext` has a method just like `UDFContext` from Pig to retrieve the Job configuration. So you could just do the following:

```
@Override
public void configure(MapredContext context) {
    Configuration conf = context.getJobConf();  
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this. It solved my problem beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

As of hive 1.2 there are 2 approaches.

**1. Overriding configure method from GenericUDF**

```
  @Override
   public void configure(MapredContext context) {
       super.configure(context);
       someProp = context.getJobConf().get(HIVE_PROPERTY_NAME);
   }
```

Above(1) won't work in all the cases. Works only in MapredContext.
Every query has to be force map/reduce jobs, to do that  set

```
set hive.fetch.task.conversion=minimal/none;
set hive.optimize.constant.propagation=false;
```

.
with above properties set, you will hit major performance problems, especially for smaller queries.

**2. Using SessionState**

```
 SessionState ss = SessionState.get();
     if (ss != null) {
          this.hiveConf = ss.getConf();
          someProp = this.hiveConf.get(HIVE_PROPERTY_NAME);
          LOG.info("Got someProp: " + someProp);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to hive command line

```
hive> set MY_CONF='foobar';
```

your variable should be listed when hitting the command

```
hive> set;
```

Now, consider you have below 
**Jar**: MyUDF.jar 
**UDF calss**: MySampleUDF.java which accepts a String value. 
**Table**: employee

```
hive> ADD JAR /MyUDF.jar
hive> CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION testUDF AS 'youpackage.MySampleUDF';
hive> SELECT testUDF(${MY_CONF}) from employee;
```

Answer (score -3):

there are lots of example, shared , so you can find all required details over google :).

A Small Example which was describe in shared link:

```
hive> ADD JAR assembled.jar;
hive> create temporary function hello as 'com.test.example.UDFExample';
hive> select hello(firstname) from people limit 10;
```

Please check link for reference which I normally Used to:
[Link1](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli#LanguageManualCli-HiveResources)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995290/how-to-pass-hive-conf-variable-in-hive-udf)

Comment: I am asking about passing configurations from hive script, where UDF is called, to the UDF. Your links are about how to write hive UDFs, which are not so relevant in this case.

Comment: My Bad, though have you tried with Hive Resources [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli) its having feature of Adding/deleting/archiving one or more files, jars, or archives to the list of resources in the distributed cache.